# How to keep the session of user login?

Tags: java, android, session

I have an app that requires user to register. I've got the app conected to PHP in my server to do the logic of register/login and so, this is not problem at all.

But, I want to keep a session of the user in local, so the user doesn't have to login again every time he runs the app.

So, I want something like this:

- First time user, he opens the app, register and login.
- Do some stuff with the app and closes it.
- Open the app again, the user is recognized so he doesn't need to login again.

I only need to store an ID and a Username (both fetched from the DB in the login php method). What's the best way to do this??

I've thought about doing a custom preference, store the data in files or even a local DB (sqlite). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, preferences would work.  In your `onCreate()`:

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefs(this);
```

And in some function that gets called after the user logs in:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
edit.putString("app_username", username);
edit.putInt("app_userid", userId);
edit.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference for this purpose..
try below code....:

```
PreferenceManager pm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefs(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pm.edit();
edit.putString("user", username);
edit.putInt("pwd", password);
edit.commit();
```