# Android: how to keep the login username stored in the phone as user sending the data to the database server

Tags: android, database, session, authentication, logout

I've been doing alot of searching around the website but not even sure if i got all the keywords correctly.
I've found this link but I needed more coding samples.

[How to keep the session of user login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608452/how-to-keep-the-session-of-user-login)

I would like more sample coding on keeping the user's info when logged in. As that user sends the data to the server it will identify that user sent that data.

For example, I login as 9999. I send the data 123456789 as a book number to the database server.
the database will show

user-9999 book number 123456789

Another thing I need as sample coding for this similar project is how to input a code to completely logout. As user's cant log out and only their supervisor who knows the code can approve and logout for them by putting in the numbers.

Thanks
Merrill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'd post this in a comment, but my account doesn't yet have adequate commenting permissions.)

Are you strictly trying to figure out http session management within the Android app, or are you also trying to figure out session management in a server-side application?

Comment: im trying to figure out the phone itself saving the username. Since the phone will be the one sending the data to the webserver (which I succeed in being able to send data as text file to the http//xxx.php) I need to make sure the data being sent is from this specific user '9999' or whatever the users number to login. As for logout I am planning to put a hardcode number that only the supervisor would know to complete the logout but i cant figure out how to put that code together for 'logout' option.

Comment: So, what do you have so far?  Where exactly are you stuck?  If you're still looking for help with search terms, I'd try things like "android http session management" and "android password management".  Also, Reto Meier's post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785973 is worth reading.

Comment: I wasn't sure what exactly was the correct keyword to search for but I think the words and link you gave me would help me alot. thanks!